# Cannot convert method group... NOT missing parentheses

Tags: c#, methods, boolean, console-application, parentheses

```
bool connected = false;    

if (isConnected())  //if(isConnected() == true) also doesn't work
        {
          //code
        }
        else {
           connect();
        }

public bool isConnected() {
    if (nextEvent != "null" && !nextEvent.Contains(getEvent("disconnected"))) {
        connected = true;
    }
    return connected;
}
```

Getting the error:

> Cannot convert method group 'isConnected' tot non-delegate type 'bool'.

Why? I've looked this up and in most cases, people forget to put parentheses after the function name, like this:

```
if(isConnected) { // .... }
```

Which is not the case for me. What's wrong?

Comment: Please provide a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/), this sounds like you do in fact have the common error you mention and just missed it.

Comment: That's odd. I copied all the code into a new project and now it works without error. Guess that solves it!

Comment: Maybe you also had a bool variable/field called `isConnected`? That would have confused things, resulting in the error you mentioned.

Comment: could you try make the method static? as of now you usually need an instance of an object to call it like: `myClass.isConnected()` or alternatively call `this.isConnected()`

Comment: @Jan Doerrenhaus, nope! I triple checked. Maybe the compiler was just confused. I copied the exact same code into a new project and it started working. :P

Comment: @JanDoerrenhaus you also should get an "ambiguous reference Error" and not a "Cannot Convert"

Comment: @Vogel612 What? No. Ambiguous reference is something else entirely. It means you are `using` two namespaces which both have a type of the given name in them.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably trying to define function inside other function, if so put the function in out side function, suppose the code for calling is inside `YourFun()` then take `isConnected()` definition out side `YourFun()`

```
void YourFun()
{
    bool connected = false;    

    if (isConnected())  //if(isConnected() == true) also doesn't work
    {
          //code
    }
    else {
           connect();
    }
}

public bool isConnected() {
    if (nextEvent != "null" && !nextEvent.Contains(getEvent("disconnected"))) {
        connected = true;
    }
    return connected;
}
```

Comment: Yes it function should not be in other function, show us complete code, excluding the code that is irrelevant